# Heartbeats vs. Polling for Failure Detection in Distributed Systems

Tags: distributed-computing, polling, heartbeat

Distributed system failures can be detected either via periodic heartbeats or via periodic polling. It seems polling is more prevalent than heartbeats (e.g., load balancers prefer polling over heartbeats). Under what circumstances should one method be preferred over the other?

Answer (score 0):

In the end IMO it comes down to push v pull, polling is advantageous in the sense that it's easy to implement in a way that it is moderately scalable, and it's probably less chatty, heartbeats in of themselves can follow a push, pull, or a push then pull paradigm, polling is obviously pull based.

Answer (score 0):

Polling and Heartbeat are the two main approaches to
implement the monitoring in the failure detectors.

The polling approach is a query/reply based approach used to
monitor the processes. In this technique, when a
process **p** tracks another process **q**, process **p** sends a query
message to **q** and wait until it gets a reply to this message from
**q**. **p** will suspect **q** if **p** does not get a reply after a given time.

In the heartbeat approach, every monitoring process **p**
receives periodic heartbeat messages from every monitored
process **q** as a notification that it is still alive. Monitoring
process **p** will suspect **q** if **p** does not receive a heartbeat
message from **q** after a given time

Answer (score 0):

The difference is already explained. So I will share my thoughts on which one to go for w.r.t monitoring failures.

If you are working on a large scale distributed system, then heartbeats will be a good approach, with multiple applications running, it will be easy to manage and generate failure alerts as required. And in case of failure, once client application is recovered, it will send heartbeat, instead of monitoring application polling periodically (if not implemented correctly can generate a lot of noise for your system)

Heartbeat use-cases: Most of the trading platforms (Ex: reconciliation / managing trade feed services), services to monitor Hypervisor / DC health (Ex: VMware ESX), if you are managing / maintaining a platform used by others (Ex: Resource Manager, Kafka, Elasticsearch, etc), especially for time critical systems, which requires zero to minimal data loss or way to recover fast.

Polling use-cases: FW Management system, for applications / platforms which doesn't have to provide continuous availability to end users, with acceptable downtime or there can be a delay in generating alerts upon failure.